# Visual Studio 2019 VB.Net DateTimePicker, Set MinDate and make past dates read-only

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to create a custom control that references DateTimePicker that when MinDate is set, rather than blanking removing previous dates it sets them to read only? I have the form to be able to be read and edited at a later date so I would like to be able to see the value of the previous date entered without it defaulting to datetime.Today which the min date will be set to. For example: if a create a task with the duedate of tomorrow, I would like to be able to open the form next week and see the value in the DateTimePicker was set to.

[image]

If I open the Task form after the due date has past it will open the due date set rather than today. But when creating a task the MinDate that will be allow to be selected is today.

Edit -Thank you jmcilhinney for translating for me,

So what you're saying is that you want to be able to set any value in code but not let the user select before a threshold value via the UI, right?

Comment: Anything is possible, just really depends on what you're doing, and **what** you're doing it with.  Can you show us a **picture** of what your control looks like and the parts that you need help with?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to be able to set any value in code but not let the user select before a threshold value via the UI, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Save the date that the user inputs to My.Settings. and have it check for the value when the program is loaded